# How to add 2 or more 3D objects to the HTML 5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new to Three.js and currently trying to develop a web-based 3d object viewer/editor. 
I referred to [thingiview.js](https://github.com/tbuser/thingiview.js?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter) and able develop functions to view,rotate,and zoom in & out. And I added a drag and droppable function to the canvas. Currently, only ".stl" (lowercase) file type works for this function.

My intention is to add another .stl file to add on the canvas and display. I have thought if it is possible to

- make an array
- store the dropped items(.stl) files to the array
- display all the available items from the array on the canvas

I'm not very advanced in JavaScript language and still learning to improve while developing this function. Please advise if I am on the right track or if there is any possible ways to achieve this. Or, possibly if there is any resources I could read up for more information.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please note that the stl tag is for C++ questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you are using Three.js. I think in three you could do things like:

```
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphere, material);
scene.add( mesh );
```

This will basically only create a sphere and put into scene tho, but you do the same with loaders. scene.add(whatever) to display in scene. To make it easier to access objects later for position change and other, you can push them into a array like so:

```
var objectArray;

(inside loader)
scene.add( mesh );
objectArray.push(mesh);
```

Then you can loop the array later to check for instances and do positioning and such.
Hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: You should initialize the array as: `var objectArray = [];`

Comment: Thank you, @Ernst and @BearProgrammer.
I tried below. 
`var items = [];
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
function addItem(){
 if(handledrop){
  var object = document.getElementById('canvas-drop');
  items.push("objects");
  for(var obj = 0; obj<items.length; obj++){
    scene.add(items[obj]);
  }
 }
}`
Actually I tried to follow this stl viewer from http://www.marcoantonini.eu/doku.php?id=3dmodel:stlviewer, and intended to accept additional items on the canvas back. But above code didnt work.So Im wondering this function supposed to be in thingiview.js or html body itself.

Comment: @user3188865, you're creating the object `var object... ` but instead of adding it to the array, you're adding a string: `items.push("object")`. I don't think that's what you want. Maybe remove the quotes?

Comment: Yes @Bear, I have tried as u advised. But, still not able to display the objects back on canvas using array. I think I not able to put these codes in the right place, which also brought me to another question. Thank you for ur suggestions.